# Can you identify this 'N' app running in the status bar?

Tags: applications, wallpaper

This 'N' thing in the status bar is new and I don't know which app it is. I've looked in the applications list but can't find anything unusual. I think it also changed the wallpaper without asking.

Does anyone recognize it?

Here it is close up:

[image: close-up]

And in the context of the screen:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It can't be a normal app. The icons on the right are from the OS, not user apps.

Comment: You really need to identify the device and the version of Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but could it be a [variation of the NFC status icon](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/216398-anyone-know-what-icon-top-bar.html)?

Comment: The phone does have NFC (Xolo X900), will look into this.

Comment: So it was NFC :)